# How to update text inside modal with the help of alpine.js

Tags: laravel-9, alpine.js

I have a order list of the data, and each `list item` has popup modal attached, when user click on any list item it should show x-data value in the popup

```
 <li x-data="{ friends: {{ $value['friends'] }}, mediId: {{$value['medid']}}  }"
                            x-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('open-modal', 'confirm-result')"</li>
<li x-data="{ friends: {{ $value['friends'] }}, mediId: {{$value['medid']}}  }"
                            x-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('open-modal', 'confirm-result')"</li>
```

below is my popup modal component i try this but it doesn't work `<h1 x-text="friends"></h1>`

```
<x-modal  maxWidth="lg" name="confirm-result" focusable>
        <form method="post" action="" class="p-6">
<h1 x-text="friends"></h1>
</form>
    </x-modal>
```

any help how to pass x-data value to modal h1.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to pass data to your modal, you will need to keep the modal in scope with your `x-data`:

```html
<div x-data="{ friends: {{ $value['friends'] }} }">
    <x-modal>
        <h1 x-text="friends"></h1>
    </x-modal>
</div>
```

However, if that isn't possible (e.g. due to CSS styling or element positioning), you can add another [$dispatch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch) instead:

```html
<li x-data="{ friends: {{ $value['friends'] }}, mediId: {{$value['medid']}} }"
    x-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('set-friends', friends); $dispatch('open-modal', 'confirm-result')"
</li>

<x-modal  maxWidth="lg" name="confirm-result" focusable x-data="{ friends: {{ $value['friends'] }} }" x-on:set-friends.window="friends = $event.detail">
    <form method="post" action="" class="p-6">
        <h1 x-text="friends"></h1>
    </form>
</x-modal>
```

Comment: exactly dispatch is the solution, however i am using foreach loop and i want when someone click on first li the data of the first should be loaded in the modal.

Comment: also i test your code and it's giving me an error Alpine Expression Error: Can't find variable:

Comment: I have not tested my code, nor do I know your base code, so I cannot guarantee full functionality. I provided a solution to your given problem. If you're using a single modal, but apply the same event to each LI item, this will still work.